# CMake: Generate one file with locations from multiple configurations

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

As the policy [CMP0026](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/policy/CMP0026.html) produces now a warning when using the `LOCATION` property I was looking into moving to `file(GENERATE` with a generator expression instead. However I came to the problem that I need to create one file with paths to the target file for all configurations. Namely this is the target launcher generation for Visual Studio which is a single XML file the contains the configurations for Debug, Release etc.

Using the `LOCATION_<config>` this was easy: Gather all of them and then simply do string magic and `configure_file` to create the file. I can't do this with `file(GENERATE` as that produces one file per configuration. I'd need that in one file or merge them right after that generation command or something like that.

How is this possible? If it wasn't then producing launcher configs will stop working when that policy is removed completely and the warning is already annoying. (`The OLD behavior for policy CMP0026 will be removed from a future version of CMake.`)

Context: The launcher templates are required to set the working dir for debugging in CMake or the default project to launch.

Comment: Is this still required with the latest CMake and Visual Studio version? They added a lot of such features within the last couple of releases.

Comment: Good idea. I found [VS_STARTUP_PROJECT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/prop_dir/VS_STARTUP_PROJECT.html) (CMake 3.6) and [VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/prop_tgt/VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY.html) (CMake 3.8) So only thing missing would be environment variables, but this helps already

Comment: CMake offers ways to access environment variables. If you start your CMake in the right console or run some magic VS command first, all variables are accessible.

Comment: I mean setting environment variables for execution of the project. In VS this is possible the same way as setting the working directory.